# Updating Statistics: Estimated Number of Rows not equal to Actual for Index Scan. Why?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2017, statistics

I am trying to understand the effect that forcing the update of statistics with a fullscan has on execution plan estimates.

I currently have the following result in the execution plan for a very simple SELECT query:
[image]

As you can see it is off by 5 rows.

I then run:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS  Person.Address WITH FULLSCAN
UPDATE STATISTICS  Person.Address [PK_Address_AddressID] WITH FULLSCAN
GO
EXEC sp_recompile 'Person.Address';
GO
SELECT * FROM Person.Address OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

However, it is still off by 5 rows. 
Why?

I know I shouldn't worry unless there is a performance problem. However, I am trying to understand the actual effect of a complete statistics update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Row count appears to only hold 6 significant digits of information (apparently called a mantissa for a float).

Consider the below example, which has a table with 11,111,111 rows. However, estimated rows is only displayed as 11,111,100.

```
USE TestDB
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.stattest
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.stattest (ID int primary key, junk char(1))

INSERT dbo.stattest
SELECT TOP 11111111 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0), 'a'
FROM master..spt_values a
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values b
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values c

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.stattest
```

Interestingly, the stats object shows all 11,111,111 rows.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.stattest WITH FULLSCAN
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_stats_properties(OBJECT_ID('dbo.stattest'),1)
```

By adding TF 2363, you can see that the rounding occurs during the cardinality estimation process.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.stattest
OPTION(
QUERYTRACEON 3604,
QUERYTRACEON 2363
)
```

> CStCollBaseTable(ID=1, CARD=1.11111e+007 TBL: dbo.stattest)